# html drop down menu color

Tags: html, css

I have a a drop down menu with color black , i use a color red when i hover on it, my problem is that when i  go to drop down menu the color turn from red to black , what i want is for example i hover on about the color of about turn red a drop down menu appears , when i go to that menu of about to color on about turn back to black, i want the color to be red until i leave the drop down menu.

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul class="drop_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
             <ul> 
               <li>contact us</li>
               <li>about us</li></ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.drop_menu > li > a:hover {
          color: red;
        }
        .drop_menu li:hover ul {
        background: #484f57;
        }
        .drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
        display:block;
        background-color:#484f57;
        color: #ddd;
        }
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?  When I make one with your provided code, it's obvious we're missing css.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5LwBb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your sub-menu inside the `<li>` tag for about like so:

```
<ul class="drop_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">about</a>
    <ul>
      <li>contact us</li>
      <li>about us</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use:

```
.drop_menu li:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

This will cause the `<a>` tag to be red when the `<li>` is hovered on and because the sub-menu `<ul>` is now within the parent `<li>` the color will stay red.

[Here](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/xcfEb) is a demo with the color of the parent menu item in red when hovering on the sub-menu.

Comment: it's not working , when i move to sub-menu the color of abut turn to black , what i want is when i move to sub-menu i want the color of about to be red .

Comment: You want the background color to be red? Currently the links change red on hover and the sub menu gets a background of black. All you have to do is add the styles to the same selector. So if you wanted the background to turn red add 'background-color: red;' to the `.drop_menu li:hover ul` selector

Comment: i don't want the background to be red , i want the color of text to be red , i don't think you understand my question , my question is : when i hover on the menu the color of text in menu turn to red, but when i move to sub-menu the color of text in menu turn to black , i want the color of text in menu to be red even i move to sub-menu .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the hover selector for the .drop_menu  instead of using it on the , which is why it currently goes back to black when you move your mouse off the anchor tag.

Something like this, instead:

```
.drop_menu:hover {
      color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use if i understand you :

```
.drop_menu a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.drop_menu > li > a:hover {
  color: red;

}
.drop_menu li ul {
  display: none;

}
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
background: #484f57;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
display:block;
background-color:#484f57;
color: #ddd;
}
```